# What is the meaning by Value of type 'streetwearbrand' has no member 'prefix' in Searchbar code and how to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have made my code for search and it shows an error. Can someone help me? Thanks

```
import UIKit

class streetwearbrand{

    var brandkeyword : String?
    var brandname : [String]?

    init(brandkeyword: String, brandname:[String]) {
        self.brandkeyword = brandkeyword
        self.brandname = brandname
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var SignUpButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var LoginButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var Streetwearbrand = [streetwearbrand]()

    var searchBrand = [String]()

    var searching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      Streetwearbrand.append(streetwearbrand.init(brandkeyword: "A", brandname:["A Cold Wall", "Acme De La Vie", "Adidas", "Anti Social Social Club"]))

      Streetwearbrand.append(streetwearbrand.init(brandkeyword: "B", brandname:["Balenciaga", "Bape", "Billionaries Boys Club"]))

     Streetwearbrand.append(streetwearbrand.init(brandkeyword: "C", brandname:["Carhartt", "Cav Empt", "CDG Play", "Champion"]))

     Streetwearbrand.append(streetwearbrand.init(brandkeyword: "D", brandname:["10 Deep"]))

     Streetwearbrand.append(streetwearbrand.init(brandkeyword: "E", brandname:["Emotionally Unavailable", "Essential"]))

    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return Streetwearbrand.count
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
          return searchBrand.count
        } else {
        return Streetwearbrand[section].brandname?.count ?? 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if searching{
            cell.textLabel?.text = searchBrand[indexPath.row]
        } else {cell.textLabel?.text = Streetwearbrand[indexPath.section].brandname?[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}

    //for title

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return Streetwearbrand[section].brandkeyword
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 40))
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 15, height: 40))
        label.text = Streetwearbrand[section].brandkeyword
        view.addSubview(label)
        return view
    }

    //to generate the height of the keyword label
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
    }

// search

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBrand = Streetwearbrand.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Streetwearbrand.filter({$0.prefix...
```

In this case `$0` is the element in the `Streetwearbrand` array, which is an instance of `streetwearbrand`.

First things first - its typical to name the class with Uppercase and the instance with lowercase, and hopefully with different names so you don't confuse yourself.  Perhaps the class should be `Streetwearbrand` and the array should be `streetweardbrandArray`, but that's personal preference.

Your issue is the class `streetwarebrand` doesn't implement a `prefix` method.  I think you want to look at one of the properties that's a string, maybe `brandkeyword` like

```
Streetwearbrand.filter({$0.brandkeyword.prefix...
```

Comment: thank you for your help.. but now it's shows errors like this Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.SubSequence?' (aka 'Optional<Substring>') and 'String' @dmorrow

Comment: `filter { $0 lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased()) }`

Comment: I try that and shows an errors like this.. "Value of type 'streetwearbrand' has no member 'lowercased' " @dmorrow

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the brandkeyword `filter { $0.brandkeyword.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased()) }`

Comment: I write the code like this searchBrand = Streetwearbrand.filter { (($0.brandkeyword?.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased()))! == searchText.lowercased()) } and it shows error Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool' and 'String' @dmorrow